# Creating xml file using ElementTree or lxml

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, lxml, elementtree

I am creating an XML file using the following code but the formatting is messed up. I am wondering if anyone has inputs on how the create a formatted xml file using elementtree or lxml for the following code..

```
data = [['SEC.12.0', '\\\\DATA\\LOC', '\\\\ftp\\location'], ['SEC.13.0', '\\\\DATA\\LOC2', '\\\\ftp\\location2']]

f = open('data.xml', 'w')
f.write('<combo>')
for line in data :
    f.write('<pro>' + line[0] + '</pro>')
    f.write ('\n')
    f.write('<dataloc>' + line[1] + '</dataloc>')
    f.write('\n')
    f.write('<ftploc>' + line[2]+ '</ftploc>')
    f.write('\n')
f.write(</combo>')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure it's a good idea to parse and dump your xml string just for prettifying. You can just pre-format your xml string like this:

```
from lxml import etree


data = [['SEC.12.0', '\\\\DATA\\LOC', '\\\\ftp\\location'], ['SEC.13.0', '\\\\DATA\\LOC2', '\\\\ftp\\location2']]

COMBO = """<combo>
    {0}
</combo>"""

ITEM = """
    <pro>{0}</pro>
    <dataloc>{1}</dataloc>
    <ftploc>{2}</ftploc>
"""

output = COMBO.format("".join([ITEM.format(*line) for line in data]))

with open('data.xml', 'w') as f:
    f.write(output)
```

FYI, here's how you can do it with `lxml` (I've changed forming xml process a bit):

```
from lxml import etree


data = [['SEC.12.0', '\\\\DATA\\LOC', '\\\\ftp\\location'], ['SEC.13.0', '\\\\DATA\\LOC2', '\\\\ftp\\location2']]

xml_string = '<combo>'
for line in data:
    xml_string += "<pro>{0}</pro>\n<dataloc>{1}</dataloc>\n<ftploc>{2}</ftploc>\n".format(*line)
xml_string += '</combo>'

parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
root = etree.fromstring(xml_string, parser)
with open('data.xml', 'w') as f:
    f.write(etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True))
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how the XML document can be created using lxml's `Element` and `SubElement` functions (no need to type any angle brackets):

```
from lxml import etree

data = [['SEC.12.0', '\\\\DATA\\LOC', '\\\\ftp\\location'],
        ['SEC.13.0', '\\\\DATA\\LOC2', '\\\\ftp\\location2']]

combo = etree.Element("combo")   # Root element of XML document

for line in data:
    etree.SubElement(combo, 'pro').text = line[0]
    etree.SubElement(combo, 'dataloc').text = line[1]
    etree.SubElement(combo, 'ftploc').text = line[2]

etree.ElementTree(combo).write("data.xml", pretty_print=True)
```

The program outputs a document called data.xml, with the following content:

```
<combo>
  <pro>SEC.12.0</pro>
  <dataloc>\\DATA\LOC</dataloc>
  <ftploc>\\ftp\location</ftploc>
  <pro>SEC.13.0</pro>
  <dataloc>\\DATA\LOC2</dataloc>
  <ftploc>\\ftp\location2</ftploc>
</combo>
```

---

The above code can be modified to work with ElementTree:

1. Change the import statement to `from xml.etree import ElementTree as etree`.
2. Remove the `pretty_print` parameter in the `write()` method.

But the output will not be pretty-printed. To work around that problem, you can use the `indent()` function from http://effbot.org/zone/element-lib.htm#prettyprint.