# creating a xml file with For Loop in python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have a txt file contains more than 100 thousands lines, and for each line I want to create a XML tree. BUT all lines are sharing the same root.

Here the txt file:

```
LIBRARY:
1,1,1,1,the
1,2,1,1,world
2,1,1,2,we
2,5,2,1,have
7,3,1,1,food
```

The desired output:

```
   <LIBRARY>
    <BOOK ID ="1">
        <CHAPTER ID ="1">
            <SENT ID ="1">
                <WORD ID ="1">the</WORD>
            </SENT>
        </CHAPTER>
    </BOOK>
    <BOOK ID ="1">
        <CHAPTER ID ="2">
            <SENT ID ="1">
                <WORD ID ="1">world</WORD>
            </SENT>
        </CHAPTER>
    </BOOK>
    <BOOK ID ="2">
        <CHAPTER ID ="1">
            <SENT ID ="1">
                <WORD ID ="2">we</WORD>
            </SENT>
        </CHAPTER>
    </BOOK>
    <BOOK ID ="2">
        <CHAPTER ID ="5">
            <SENT ID ="2">
                <WORD ID ="1">have</WORD>
            </SENT>
        </CHAPTER>
    </BOOK>
    <BOOK ID ="7">
        <CHAPTER ID ="3">
            <SENT ID ="1">
                <WORD ID ="1">food</WORD>
            </SENT>
        </CHAPTER>
    </BOOK>
</LIBRARY>
```

I use Element tree for converting txt file to xml file, this is the code I run

```
def expantree():
  lines = txtfile.readlines()
  for line in lines:
    split_line = line.split(',')
    BOOK.set( 'ID ', split_line[0])
    CHAPTER.set( 'ID ', split_line[1])
    SENTENCE.set( 'ID ', split_line[2])
    WORD.set( 'ID ', split_line[3])
    WORD.text = split_line[4]
    tree = ET.ElementTree(Root)
    tree.write(xmlfile)
```

Okay, the code is working but i didnt get the desired output, I got the following:

```
<LIBRARY>
    <BOOK ID ="1">
        <CHAPTER ID ="1">
            <SENT ID ="1">
                <WORD ID ="1">the</WORD>
            </SENT>
        </CHAPTER>
    </BOOK>
</LIBRARY>
<LIBRARY>
    <BOOK ID ="1">
        <CHAPTER ID ="2">
            <SENT ID ="1">
                <WORD ID ="1">world</WORD>
            </SENT>
        </CHAPTER>
    </BOOK>
</LIBRARY>
<LIBRARY>
    <BOOK ID ="2">
        <CHAPTER ID ="1">
            <SENT ID ="1">
                <WORD ID ="2">we</WORD>
            </SENT>
        </CHAPTER>
    </BOOK>
</LIBRARY>
<LIBRARY>
    <BOOK ID ="2">
        <CHAPTER ID ="5">
            <SENT ID ="2">
                <WORD ID ="1">have</WORD>
            </SENT>
        </CHAPTER>
    </BOOK>
</LIBRARY>
<LIBRARY>
    <BOOK ID ="7">
        <CHAPTER ID ="3">
            <SENT ID ="1">
                <WORD ID ="1">food</WORD>
            </SENT>
        </CHAPTER>
    </BOOK>
</LIBRARY>
```

How to unify the tree root , so instead of getting many root tag I get one root tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method would be to create the full tree and print it. I used the following code:

```
from lxml import etree as ET

def create_library(lines):
    library = ET.Element('LIBRARY')
    for line in lines:
        split_line = line.split(',')
        library.append(create_book(split_line))
    return library

def create_book(split_line):
    book = ET.Element('BOOK',ID=split_line[0])
    book.append(create_chapter(split_line))
    return book

def create_chapter(split_line):
    chapter = ET.Element('CHAPTER',ID=split_line[1])
    chapter.append(create_sentence(split_line))
    return chapter

def create_sentence(split_line):
    sentence = ET.Element('SENT',ID=split_line[2])
    sentence.append(create_word(split_line))
    return sentence

def create_word(split_line):
    word = ET.Element('WORD',ID=split_line[3])
    word.text = split_line[4]
    return word
```

Then your code to create the file would look like:

```
def expantree():
    lines = txtfile.readlines()
    library = create_library(lines)
    ET.ElementTree(lib).write(xmlfile)
```

If you don't want to load the entire tree in memory (you mentioned there are more than 100 thousand lines), you can manually create the  tag, write each book one at a time, then add the  tag. In this case your code would look like:

```
def expantree():
    lines = txtfile.readlines()
    f = open(xmlfile,'wb')
    f.write('<LIBRARY>')
    for line in lines:
        split_line = line.split(',')
        book = create_book(split_line)
        f.write(ET.tostring(book))
    f.write('</LIBRARY>')
    f.close()
```

I don't have that much experience with lxml, so there may be more elegant solutions, but both of these work.

Answer (score 1):

Another option which is perhaps more succinct is as follows:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
import io
import os

# Setup the test input
inbuf = io.StringIO(''.join(['LIBRARY:\n', '1,1,1,1,the\n', '1,2,1,1,world\n',
                             '2,1,1,2,we\n', '2,5,2,1,have\n', '7,3,1,1,food\n']))

tags = ['BOOK', 'CHAPTER', 'SENT', 'WORD']
with inbuf as into, io.StringIO() as xmlfile:
    root_name = into.readline()
    root = ET.ElementTree(ET.Element(root_name.rstrip(':\n')))
    re = root.getroot()
    for line in into:
        values = line.split(',')
        parent = re
        for i, v in enumerate(values[:4]):
            parent =  ET.SubElement(parent, tags[i], {'ID': v})
            if i == 3:
                parent.text = values[4].rstrip(':\n')
    root.write(xmlfile, encoding='unicode', xml_declaration=True)
    xmlfile.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)
    for line in xmlfile:
        print(line)
```

What this code does is to construct an `ElementTree` from the input data and write it to a file-like object as an XML file. This code will work either with the standard Python `xml.etree` package or with `lxml`. The code was tested using Python 3.3.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion that uses lxml (tested with Python 2.7). The code can easily be adapted to work with ElementTree too, but it's harder to get nice pretty-printed output (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/16377996/407651 for some more on this).

The input file is library.txt and the output file is library.xml.

```py
from lxml import etree

lines = open("library.txt").readlines()
library = etree.Element('LIBRARY')   # The root element 

# For each line with data in the input file, create a BOOK/CHAPTER/SENT/WORD structure
for line in lines:
    values = line.split(',')
    if len(values) == 5:
        book = etree.SubElement(library, "BOOK")
        book.set("ID", values[0])
        chapter = etree.SubElement(book, "CHAPTER")
        chapter.set("ID", values[1])
        sent = etree.SubElement(chapter, "SENT")
        sent.set("ID", values[2])
        word = etree.SubElement(sent, "WORD")
        word.set("ID", values[3])
        word.text = values[4].strip()

etree.ElementTree(library).write("library.xml", pretty_print=True)
```

Comment: I upvoted, but since SubElement allows attributes to be set as in `book = etree.SubElement(library, 'BOOK', ID=values[0])`, the set() operations can be eliminated.